# Google Cloud Messaging not working on 4.1.2 devices on a corporate network

Tags: android, networking, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented a simple GCM client and server. The client uses the [current GCM client APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) (not the [deprecated helper library](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/helper.html)). The server (C# & .NET) follows the corresponding [server guidelines](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) (using [HTTP](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)). My server runs on a machine within my company domain, so I'm connecting the client devices to a Wi-Fi access point inside the corporate network but with access to the Internet.

My problem in a nutshell is that **notifications are received fine on 4.3+ handsets, but are never received on 4.1.2 handsets when connected to the corporate Wi-Fi network**. If I connect a 4.1.2 device to our public guest Wi-Fi network the GCM messages are received as expected, but then the app can't connect to the corporate server.

I've seen some indications that GCM can fail when corporate networks have overly protective firewalls (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932342/message-is-not-getting-from-the-gcm-server/22932812#22932812)). But if it was just a firewall issue, surely the 4.3+ devices wouldn't receive any messages either?

#### Some additional details

My test handsets are as follows:

- Asus Nexus 7 (4.4.2)
- Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.4.2)
- HTC One (4.3)
- Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.1.2)
- Motorola Razr HD (4.1.2)

The server has received valid registration IDs from all five devices. On a 15-second timer it sends out a single message addressed to all five registration IDS. The response always shows that 5 messages were sent with no errors and no changed registration IDs. However, it is **always** received on the first three devices listed above, and **never** on the last two (running 4.1.2). When I debug them, the broadcast receiver isn't getting invoked at all.

I've also verified that all five devices:

- have Google Play Services 4.3.25
- have no SIM, hence no cellular data, and are on the same WiFi network
- have the correct date & time
- are registered with the same Gmail test account
- are running the same version of my client app
- have all sync settings for their Google account enabled

Comment: Can you please post your manifest in the question?

Comment: @Eran Sure, I've added it now.

Comment: Just added the build.gradle too in case that's useful.

Comment: Well, the GCM related definitions in the manifest look OK to me, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks for your help - good to have that confirmed at least.

Comment: @Eran I've got a little further and found out that the problem only occurs when the 4.1.2 devices are connected to a corporate Wi-Fi network. I've adjusted the question accordingly. If you've got any ideas I'd be very grateful to hear them.

Comment: Try to install [Firebind](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.firebind.android&hl=en) on a device that doesn't work, and use it to check if ports 5228,5229,5230 are open.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've finally figured out what the problem is. The corporate firewall is blocking traffic on the native GCM port of 5228. (5229 and 5230 are [also mentioned with relation to GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#request) but we're not seeing any attempted traffic on those ports at all.) This much is well documented elsewhere (just Google *GCM port 5228*).

What I can't find clearly documented anywhere, but we've figured out from our server logs and from running [Connection Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.borgshell.connectiontrackerfree) on the handsets, is that newer versions of Android fall back to using port 443 (the standard HTTPS port) which most firewalls allow traffic through by default. This is how our devices running newer Android versions are working even behind the firewall. I don't know precisely what Android version introduced this port 443 fallback, but it's somewhere between 4.1.2 (not working) and 4.3 (working).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the manifest entries above, but I ran into the exact issue a few days ago, the manifest *package* must match the *C2D_MESSAGE* permission package.
ie.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo.bar"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="3.1">
```

...

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<permission android:name="com.foo.bar.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.foo.bar.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

In my case the declared package did not match in order to provide an upgrade path for a previous version of the application.

Comment: I removed the manifest after it became apparent that wasn't the problem: the issue only occurs when the solution is connected to a corporate network. The manifest is fine, and the package does indeed match the C2D_MESSAGE permission. If you're interested, you can still see the manifest in the [revisions to this page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23732611/revisions).

Comment: Looking at the revisions, I noticed that the receiver is not exported, it might be worth a try: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html Let me know if it works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: The receiver is exported! Not sure why you think it isn't. Also, please read the question and my comments again before commenting further: the manifest is not the problem.